# Which one is the correct syntax?

Tags: jquery

Friends, I've one question to ask. Which one is the correct syntax in jquery to get the last row of a gridview or is there any difference in the following codes:--

```
 var rowCount = $('#GridView1 tr').length;

 or

 var rowCount = $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr:last");
```

Please help me to resolve the problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: rule #1: don't ask two questions in the same *question* ;) especially when they're not related to each other.

Comment: @MatthiasKoch actually both of them are related integrally in the same problem.So I asked..

Comment: Should I edit the question, and ask one by one?

Comment: Yes, it would be better :) ASP.Net and jquery are two distinct fields of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access to global variable. First is correct and most preferable.